# How can I reconfigure this store.js file from Redux to @Redux/toolkit?

Tags: redux, blockchain, redux-toolkit

[image][image]

I am following a tutorial video.
I am at the stage of developing UI for an exchange.
I am at the stage where I producing a store.js file.
I have the completed code (image 1), however my text editor tells me the format is depracated.
I need to reformat it for redux/toolkit.
Please advise how I can do this.

I will also need to ass redux/toolkit to package.json.
Please include any other possible adjustments I will need to make to other files.
Thanks

I have tried to adjust the code by removing Middleware, devTools and enhancer, but I am still receiving errors when launching on localhost.

Answer (score 2):

If that tutorial shows you `createStore`, run and never look back!
`createStore` has that deprecation warning to stop people following outdated tutorials immediately at the beginning and not waste their time with outdated knowledge.

Modern Redux with Redux Toolkit is fundamentally different from legacy Redux and if your tutorial starts with `createStore`, it will continue to teach you a style of Redux that is four times the code, much more confusing and error-prone.

Redux Toolkit is the official recommendation since 2019 and if that tutorial shows you legacy Redux, it will probably also teach you all kinds of other outdated knowledge (like React class components or the React-Redux `connect` function).

Please follow the [Official Redux Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) instead, as that teaches Redux Toolkit from the start.

And if that tutorial was teaching other things, please look for other sources for that as well.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I will take a closer look at the Official Redux Tutorial and source more up-to-date developer tutorials for the UI aspect of the blockchain project.

Comment: Honestly, if that project is so outdated on this part I wouldn't bet on any other part of it being up to date. But in the end, it's your call.